# Print each word on different line which are separated by comma

Tags: bash

I want to print different words in different rows which are separated by the comma using bash script.

```
ent0
ent4
ent1,ent5
ent2,ent6
ent3,ent7
ent29,ent30
```

I want to print each word in different line.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is this the input? What's the desired output then? Or is it the output? What did the input look like? Where is the code you wrote to solve the problem, and what specific problem did you have with it? Does it have to be Bash? What's separated by comma? Lines or words? The wording is ambiguous.

Comment: Hi that  is the input , i need the output is like this

Comment: Input:ent0
ent4
ent1,ent5
ent2,ent6
ent3,ent7
ent29,ent30

Comment: output should be like this:

Comment: ent0
ent4
ent1
ent5
ent2
ent6
ent3
ent7
ent29
ent30

Comment: You should [edit] the question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tr`,

```
echo 'ent0 ent4 ent1,ent5 ent2,ent6 ent3,ent7 ent29,ent30' | tr ',' '\n'
```

Using `sed`,

```
echo 'ent0 ent4 ent1,ent5 ent2,ent6 ent3,ent7 ent29,ent30' | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

Both will produce,

```
ent0 ent4 ent1
ent5 ent2
ent6 ent3
ent7 ent29
ent30
```

EDIT:

Your requirement is not clear enough. If you want to split by both commas and spaces,

```
echo 'ent0 ent4 ent1,ent5 ent2,ent6 ent3,ent7 ent29,ent30' | tr ', ' '\n'
```

or

```
echo 'ent0 ent4 ent1,ent5 ent2,ent6 ent3,ent7 ent29,ent30' | sed 's/\(,\| \)/\n/g;'
```

This will produce,

```
ent0
ent4
ent1
ent5
ent2
ent6
ent3
ent7
ent29
ent30
```

If the content is in a file, say `input.txt`, use it instead of `echo`.

```
tr ', ' '\n' <input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can do it quite simply with `IFS`, `printf` and *command substitution*, e.g.

```
$ IFS="$IFS,"; printf "%s\n" $(<file.txt)
ent0
ent4
ent1
ent5
ent2
ent6
ent3
ent7
ent29
ent30
```

(don't forget to reset `IFS` to its default `$' \t\n'` (space tab newline) when done. You can save `oldifs="$IFS"`, then run your command, and set `IFS="$oldifs"` afterwards as an easy reset)